# Udp streams in vlc mosaic

Tags: windows, stream, udp, vlc, mosaic

I'm trying to regroup three UDP streams in one mosaic, using VLC 2.0.5 on Windows 7. I don't need to stream it; but just to display it on my screen. But I'm doing it wrong, hope some one could help.

Here is my conf file :

```
new 1 broadcast enabled
setup 1 input "udp://@1.2.3.1:1234"
setup 1 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=1,height=144,width=180},select=video,dst=bridge-out{id=1},select=audio}
new 2 broadcast enabled
setup 2 input "udp://@1.2.3.2:1234"
setup 2 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=2,height=144,width=180},select=video,dst=bridge-out{id=2},select=audio}
new 6 broadcast enabled
setup 6 input "udp://@1.2.3.3:1235"
setup 6 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=3,height=144,width=180},select=video,dst=bridge-out{id=3},select=audio} 
new BackGround broadcast enabled loop
setup BackGround input "file:///C:/file.bmp"
setup BackGround output output #transcode{sfilter=mosaic,vcodec=mp2v,vb=500,scale=1}:bridge-in{delay=400,id-offset=100}:display
setup BackGround option file-caching=300

control 1 play
control 2 play
control 6 play
control BackGround play
```

And this is my command : 
./vlc --color --vlm-conf --mosaic-width=360 --mosaic-height=288 --mosaic-keep-picture --mosaic-rows=2 --mosaic-cols=2 --mosaic-position=1 --mosaic-order=1,2,3,4 ."mosaic.vlm.conf"

Answer (score 1):

After `--vlm-conf` you should specify the input vlm config file; You specified it at the end!
try this:

vlc --color --vlm-conf mosaic.conf --mosaic-width 360 --mosaic-height 288 --mosaic-rows 2 --mosaic-cols 2 --mosaic-order 1,2,3,4